# setTimeout not working as expected in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

I have the following code that I took off from a plugin. I have very less experience and knowledge with JavaScript. I am trying to delay the change of text in html. Here's what the code i have:

```
function printResult() {
    var res;
    var blah="OKAY B****!";
    
    if(win[a.pos] === win[b.pos] && win[a.pos] === win[c.pos]) {
        res = "You Win!";
    } else {
        res = "You Lose";   
    }

    $('#result').html(res);

    if(res=='You Lose'){
        setTimeout($('#result').html(blah),3000);
    }else{}
}
```

The text in `#result` changes but it changes instantly without the delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function(){$('#result').html(blah)},3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#result').html(blah)
},3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(function(){
//your code
}, 3000 );
```

Answer (score 1):

The function setTimeout take a function as first parameter :

```
setTimeout(function()
{
  $('#result').html(blah)
}, 3000 );
```

Or:

```
function update()
{
  $('#result').html(blah)
}
setTimeout(update, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#result').html(blah)
},3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout requires a function to be passed as argument.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#result').html(blah)
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use either:

```
setTimeout("$('#result').html(blah)",3000);
```

or

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#result').html(blah)
},3000);
```